# how to make a container fixed in slivers flutter

Tags: flutter, containers, fixed

I want a container/sliver to be fixed below SliverAppBar and above SliverList.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: catLoading
              ? CircularProgress()
              : AnimatedContainer ()
          ),
```

I want this sliver to be fixed below SliverAppBar and above SliverList.

Comment: Can you share your `SliverAppBar` implementation?